# Find exact full text match in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index including ~50K documents with multiple fields. One of the fields is "content" which contains a text (can be just few words or very large articles).
Across the documents, there are many duplicates with respect to the "content" field.
I would like to add a group_id field which will indicate to which group of "content" duplicate documents it belongs.

I tried using "match" and "more_like_this" but they don't seem to return the exact duplicates, but rather a near-duplicate ones.

Example:
Given the following index:

`{
"author": "name1",
"content": "text1"
},
{
"author": "name2",
"content": "text2"
}
{
"author": "name3",
"content": "text1"
}
{
"author": "name4",
"content": "text2"
}
{
"author": "name5",
"content": "text3"
}`

I would like to get:

`{
"author": "name1",
"content": "text1",
"group_id: 0
},
{
"author": "name2",
"content": "text2",
"group_id: 1
}
{
"author": "name3",
"content": "text1",
"group_id: 0
}
{
"author": "name4",
"content": "text2",
"group_id: 1
}
{
"author": "name5",
"content": "text3",
"group_id: 2
}`

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess that content in your case is an analyzed field - that's the default and also you need it to be able to do full-text search queries. But that means it's not actually indexed in it's full raw form, so your Elasticsearch can't find an exact string match for that field. You can only find exact string matches for not analyzed fields by using the following type mapping:

```
{
    "content": {
        "type":     "string",
        "index":    "not_analyzed"
    }
}
```

However! This is actually a pretty bad idea in your case for two reasons: First, you won't be able to do full-text searches on this field any more, so you'll have to index it twice, with and without analyzing. Second, because it can have rather large values, which is inefficient to index and search as a whole.

Your actual requirement isn't to do large string matching with Elasticsearch, it's to group your documents by the content value. A better way to do this would be to add a field to your documents that holds a digest (hash) of the content field and then group by that field. The digest doesn't need to a string field, it actually makes sense to keep it numeric. Look into some hashing algorithms designed for uniqueness and speed, like [MurmurHash3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MurmurHash) which can produce either 32-bit or 128-bit hashes. Then iterate over all your documents and update them.

Comment: Seems like a good idea, i will try it. BTW, why does it make sense to keep the digest numeric rather than string (say, md5)?

Comment: Any digest starts out numeric - it's a bunch of bits (128 in case of md5) - you encode it into a string representation to make it more readable/printable. So keeping it numeric is simply a more compact way of representing the value - more efficient to store, index and search. Take the 32-bit variant of Murmur3 for example - storing it numerically takes 32 bits (i.e. 4 bytes or one long), encoding into a string with the most compact *printable* representation possible is base85 (40 bits, 5 bytes), followed by base64 (44  bits padded out to 48 because it's 6 bytes).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer and details! (my up-vote doesn't count yet)

Comment: Elasticsearch can handle that by itself without storing source data twice: use multi fields mapping: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html. Your need is the one used as example in the doc. not analyzed does not mean that it does not use a lucene index and, thus, a hash when searching.

Comment: A raw field will store a copy of the values in the index. Those might be quite large according to the original question.